# MYSQL + PHP : It is possible to union results from one table with data provided by an array?

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario:
We have a table where we store our data but also we got some data from an external  API. It is possible, to append this external data to our query results so to be able to apply WHERE and ORDER BY conditon. 
Example:

```
$a = array(array('RegDate' => '02-10-2018',
                 'JobTitle' => 'Web Designer'
           ),
           array('RegDate' => '03-10-2018',
                 'JobTitle' => 'Account Manager'
           ),
           array('RegDate' => '01-10-2018',
                 'JobTitle' => 'Web Designer'
           ),
           ...
     );


$SQL = SELECT RegDate, JobTitle, CandidateName UNION ALL SELECT $a[]['RegDate'] ,$a[]['JobTitle'] WHERE JobTitle LIKE '%Account%' ORDER BY RegDate DESC
```

Comment: I don't see the point of bringing MySQL into the picture here, since your array data already exists on the PHP side.  Instead, just run the `SELECT` without the union and then concatenate the array data to the result set on the PHP side.

Comment: Or, you can use multiple Union ALL. It will be ugly though!

Comment: Can be the easiest way to add it so I'll save a lot of time and save me to recode almost everything. This is a small bit from a script that includes pagination, templates and classes. I'll take multiple UNION I guess until I'll have time to recode it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably, deleguate your logic to php instead of MySQL here. Retrieve data from Database then append external data to it:

- 1 - execute query, get data from DB.
- 2 - Append external data to data previously returned by database
- 3 - Sort resulting array